# Show that aH and bH contain the same number of elements in G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G be a finite group and H a subgroup of G. Let a be an element of G and aH = {ah : h is an element of H} be a left coset of H. If B is an element of G as well show that aH and bH contain the same number of elements in G

Answer (score 0):

Sketch:

Construct a bijection between the two sets.  For instance, let
$$
\varphi:aH\rightarrow bH
$$
be given by $\varphi(ah)=bh$.  Now, prove that this is a bijection.

- To show that this is an injection, suppose that $\varphi(ah_1)=\varphi(ah_2)$.  This implies that $bh_1=bh_2$ or that $h_1=h_2$.
- To show that this is surjective, let $bh_3\in bH$, then $\varphi(ah_3)=bh_3$.

It is also important to verify that $\varphi$ is really a function.  This can be done by checking that the function is well-defined.  In other words, that if $ah_1=ah_2$, then $h_1=h_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $a\in G$ and define $L_a:H\to G$ by $h\mapsto ah.$ The image of this map is obviously $aH$. On the other hand, if $ah_1=ah_2$ then $a^{-1}ah_1=a^{-1}ah_2\Rightarrow h_1=h_2$. Thus, $L_a$ is a bijection so $|H|=|
aH|.$ And since $a$ is arbitrary, we have $|aH|=|H|=|bH|$ for any $a,b\in G$.