# Conclude the number of elements in $H$ divides the number of elements in $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Show that if $aH$ intersect $bH$ is not empty, then $aH$ and $bH$ contain an equal number of elements in $G$. Conclude the number of elements in $H$ divides the number of elements in $G$.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3485087/show-that-ah-and-bh-contain-the-same-number-of-elements-in-g)

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_1H, a_2H, \ldots, a_mH$ be the set of all distinct cosets.  Recall that any two distinct cosets are disjoint.  Then, since $|a_iH| = |a_jH|$ for all  $i, j$, we take $\sum_{k=1}^m|a_k H| = m|H| = |G|$.

Answer (score 1):

Two cosets $aH$ and $bH$ intersect iff $a=bh$ for some $h\in H$.  Thus if they intersect they are equal.

It follows that the cosets *partition* $G$.  Since they all have the same order,  $\vert H\vert\mid\vert G\vert$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, a much stronger statement holds:  with $H$ a subgroup of the finite group $G$, we have

$aH \cap bH \ne \emptyset \Longleftrightarrow aH = bH, \tag 1$

for if

$k \in aH \cap bH, \tag 2$

we have

$\exists h_1, h_2 \in H, \; ah_1 = k = bh_2; \tag 3$

but then

$a^{-1}b = h_1h_2^{-1} \in H, \tag 4$

which implies

$a^{-1}bH = H, \tag 5$

or

$aH = bH. \tag 6$

Clearly $aH$ and $bH$ are of the same cardinality if (6) binds.

In fact, $aH$ and $bH$ have the same number of elements whether or not (1) holds.  Consider the map

$\theta: aH \to bH, \; \theta(ah) = ba^{-1}(ah) = bh; \tag 7$

$\theta$ is clearly surjective, since (7) shows

$\theta(ah) = bh \tag 8$

for any $bh \in bH$; it is also injective, since

$\theta(ah_1) = \theta(ah_2) \Longrightarrow bh_1 = bh_2 \Longrightarrow h_1 = h_2; \tag 9$

since $\theta$ is bijective, the number of elements in $aH$ and $bH$ is the same.  Now every $a \in G$ is in *some* $aH$, namely $aH$ itself (recall that $a = ae \in aH$, where $e$ is the identity element of $G$); since the $aH$ are either disjoint are identical (by (1)), $G$ is partitioned into the disjoint cosets of $H$, each with an equal number of elements; thus the cardinality of $G$ is a multiple of the cardinality of $H$.